# Information about WSDL in salesforce

Tags: c#, wsdl, enterprise, partner-wsdl

I am integrating salesforce in my ASP.NET application and I am bit confused with the WSDL file they are having. My requirement is like I want to make an ASP.NET so that it can support all the organization. So can any one please help me which one would be the WSDL that I need to use, I am confused between Enterprise and Partner WSDL files. If I am using Enterprise WSDL then I am able to create an object of Account, Leads, Contact and all but If I am using partner WSDL then I am unable to get the class name on any one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://salesforceapexcodecorner.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/difference-between-partner-and.html) is a really good explanation and you would've been able to find it if you simply typed "Salesforce differences between partner and enterprise WSDL" on google.

> Enterprise WSDL - This WSDL document is for customers who want to
> build an integration with their Salesforce organization only.It is
> strongly typed, which means that it contains objects and fields with
> specific data types, such as int and string. Customers who use the
> enterprise WSDL document must download and re-consume it whenever
> their organization makes a change to its custom objects or fields or
> whenever they want to use a different version of the API.
>
> Partner WSDL - This WSDL document is for customers, partners, and ISVs
> who want to build an integration that can work across multiple
> Salesforce organizations, regardless of their custom objects or
> fields. It is loosely typed, which means that you work with name-value
> pairs of field names and values instead of specific data types. The
> partner WSDL document only needs to be downloaded and consumed once
> per version of the API.

A knowledge article regarding this question can also be found [here](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004760&language=en_US)

Most of the time I have been doing integration for only 1 particular SF instance and I've always used the Enterprise WSDL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So can you please suggest me which one is good. Like i am having an application, i am allowing my user to connect to their salesforce account and after that they can manage salesfroce from my application. So I think PartnerWSDL should be used. Am i right?

Comment: The last sentence in the answer given by @Bachovski is key. Code generated from the Enterprise WSDL is easier to use, but if your app is intended to connect to any organization and access any data then the Partner WSDL gives you that flexibility.

Comment: That's exactly right Keith!